# How to Determine What SAS Components are Installed

Tags: sas, components

It seems like a simple question, but for those without a cooperative IT department, it isn't.

When SAS starts, a short list of components is given.  For instance, when I start mine, I get:

```
NOTE: Updated analytical products:

      SAS/STAT 13.1
      SAS/ETS 13.1
      SAS/OR 13.1
      SAS/IML 13.1
      SAS/QC 13.1
```

This list is not exhaustive, however.  As explained by [How to find your SAS version and components list](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2012/11/12/how-to-find-your-sas-version-and-components-list/), there exist undocumented procedures which list components.

In particular,

```
proc setinit;
run;
```

and

```
proc product_status;
run;
```

While both of these seem to list installed components, the outputs, at least for me, are not a bijection.  The output for `setinit` lists far more components than `product_status`.

So, aside from looking at the receipt from SAS, how can a SAS user definitively know what components she has access to?

PS: I tried left-down-left-right-down-right-left-left-right-right, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `up-up-down-down-left-right-left-right-b-a-start` instead?

But really, download and run this macro:

http://support.sas.com/kb/20/390.html

It will definitively tell you everything you'd ever want to know about what's installed.